# Breaking a simple Captcha

Tags: captcha

For testing purpose, I need to break this captcha:

http://wapforum.us/web/img.php

As you can see, this is a very simple captcha with only 4 digits of numbers. Any sample code will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Masnun

Comment: Testing how to break complex captchas perhaps?

Comment: You can see perhaps why we might be reticent to help someone who may be conducting nefarious activities. Why do you need to break this?

Comment: I decoded it for you, it's 9929.

Comment: OMG! That's evil. It changes _every single_ time. Well, I'm stumped. :-)

Comment: I needed this for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. download image
Step 2. Run image through simple OCR software.  There are MANY different ones with full api's you can buy.
Step 3. Done.

Note: I have no problem providing this information because, quite frankly, it's extremely easy to figure out.